# how to loop line from `readline.createInterface` method?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have blow code to read a text file line by line but it complains about an error on the `for loop`. `Type 'Interface' must have a '[Symbol.asyncIterator]()' method that returns an async iterator.ts(2504)`

It seems relating to the `rl` interface created from `readline.createInterface`.

```
const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('test.text');

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fileStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity,
  });

  for await (const line of rl) {
   ...
```

Comment: You have to listen for the `line` event instead of using a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to read the stream is to use `rl.on('line', callback)`

```js
function onLine(line) {
  console.log(line);
}

rl.on('line', onLine);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-her3vv?file=index.js

---

`for await` should work provided it is inside of an `async` function and your node version is greater than 11.14: https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#rlsymbolasynciterator

```js
async function readLines() {
  for await (const line of rl) {
    console.log(line);
  }
}

readLines();
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-rquour?file=index.js